# Not receiving result of Android In-App Purchase using API v3

Tags: android, api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to work my way through the version 3 API of Android In-App Billing and have come across the following issue:

If I start a purchase with [`launchPurchaseFlow`](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Purchase), it displays the purchase dialog as expected and let's me complete the purchase. After the purchase is completed, the product is then reported as owned if I request the SKU details again. So the purchase process itself works as expected.

What doesn't work are the notifications of the purchase itself. The `OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener` that I pass to `launchPurchaseFlow` never gets called. Neither if I cancel the purchase nor if I complete it.

I turned on logging for the `IabHelper` class and get the following output in LogCat:

```
IabHelper: Starting in-app billing setup.
IabHelper: Billing service connected.
IabHelper: Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
IabHelper: In-app billing version 3 supported for <my app>
IabHelper: Subscriptions AVAILABLE.

IabHelper: Starting async operation: refresh inventory
IabHelper: Querying owned items, item type: inapp
IabHelper: Package name: <my app>
IabHelper: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
IabHelper: Owned items response: 0
IabHelper: Continuation token: null
IabHelper: Querying SKU details.
IabHelper: Got sku details: <my test product>
IabHelper: Querying owned items, item type: subs
IabHelper: Package name: <my app>
IabHelper: Calling getPurchases with continuation token: null
IabHelper: Owned items response: 0
IabHelper: Continuation token: null
IabHelper: Querying SKU details.
IabHelper: Ending async operation: refresh inventory

IabHelper: Starting async operation: launchPurchaseFlow
IabHelper: Constructing buy intent for <my test product>, item type: inapp
IabHelper: Launching buy intent for <my test product>. Request code: 1
```

And that's where it ends.

My activity receives an [`onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause()) event when the purchase dialog is shown and an [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume()) event when the dialog goes away again (both, if the purchase is cancelled or completed). Both of these events currently do nothing in my app other than a `System.out.println(...)`.

Is this a bug in the API? Or is there something I need to set up first? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging through the source for `IabHelper`, I found the problem:

The result of the purchasing intent will be sent to the Activity's [`onActivityResult(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) method. From there, it needs to be manually forwarded to the `IabHelper's` `handleActivityResult(...)` method with something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (myIabHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) return;
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

This fixes the issue, both for successful and aborted purchases.

"Yay!" for comprehensive documentation...