# Difference between PendingIntent.send(...) and Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(...)

Tags: android, android-intent

There seem to be (at least) two ways to send [Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) in Android:

- [`PendingIntent.send(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#send(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20android.app.PendingIntent.OnFinished,%20android.os.Handler))
- [`Activity.startIntentSenderForResult(`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int))[`PendingIntent.getIntentSender()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getIntentSender())[`, ...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int))

Other than the fact that the latter only works starting API level 5 and that the results are passed back in a different way (via [`PendingIntent.OnFinished`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.OnFinished.html) vs. [`Activity.onActivityResult(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))) is there any fundamental difference between the two?

I find the first one a lot more convenient as it can be entirely encapsulated inside a library without requiring the calling activity to override `onActivityResult(...)` to forward the result ([like this: yuck!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30657332/not-receiving-result-of-android-in-app-purchase-using-api-v3/30658691#30658691)). Is it ok to still use that approach?

*A quick clarification, because I've seen someone complain about this on another question:                 The methods above are not static methods. I wrote them that way simply for readability.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like these two approaches are very different:

- The `start...forResult(...)` methods start an intent or sub-activity in a way that allows for a result to be returned to the activity that executed the `start...forResult(...)`. The result will be passed back to the activity's `onActivityResult(...)` method.
- All other ways of launching intents or sub-activities (including `PendingIntent.send(...)`) act in a fire-and-forget-manner and don't allow for any results to be returned. The `OnFinished` handler is called as soon as the launch is sent, whether or not it takes a while to complete. The data passed into this handler, therefore, does not necessarily have anything to do with what you would otherwise receive via `onActivityResult(...)`. In fact, in my case, the `OnFinished` handler is always called right away, before the dialog of the sub-activity even shows up, with a `resultCode` of `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

What a mess...