# How to get results via BroadcastReceiver from a given IntentSender

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I know how to do the following

- Get results of a `PendingIntent` via a `BroadcastReceiver` (e.g. launching a chooser and getting the results after the user makes a choice)
- Get results of an `IntentSender` via an activity's `onActivityResult` by calling `startIntentSenderForResult`

However, what I need to do is launch the `IntentSender` but get the results back via a `BroadcastReceiver`. Note that `IntentSender` is given to me, so I have no access to the original `PendingIntent` corresponding to the `IntentSender`.

Is there a way to do this, perhaps by bundling additional intents to `intentSender.sendIntent()`?

I have also read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30673798/difference-between-pendingintent-send-and-activity-startintentsenderforresu) and have verified that the `onFinished` callback in `sendIntent()` fires right away and doesn't actually return the results of the intent being launched.

*Context*
I'm doing [companion device pairing](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/companion-device-pairing) using Android's `CompanionDeviceManager`. When it finds a device, it gives me `IntentSender chooserLauncher`. It expects an activity to call `startIntentSenderForResult()` with `chooserLauncher` and get the results back from the activity. However, this does not work for me because I'm developing a library and I don't want the results delivered to the activity, but rather to a `BroadcastReceiver` that I own.

Comment: Did u got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible.

Only an `Activity` can call `startActivityForResult()` and that will launch an `Activity`. The result can only be returned to an `Activity` in `onActivityResult()`. There is no way to have the result be returned directly to a `BroadcastReceiver`.  It doesn't work that way.

You would have to have the user of your library receive the result in his `Activity.onActivityResult()` and pass it to your library via whatever means you can provide.